# Is there any way to measure image reflow with chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, dom, aspect-ratio

Like in the title, is there any way to measure image reflow with chrome/other tools? I would like to measure performance benefit with and without "padding-bottom hack" for many images on site. I was trying to use audits/performance tabs and performance API but it's not giving me any decent results.

Comment: What about more tools > rendering? But I'm suprised performance tab is not enaugh because painting is there included.

Comment: @Zydnar both rendering tab and performance tab are not enough due to lack of solid numbers. I tried to test it with and without image reflow issue on the same site and I didn't find any big differences in numbers (as expected).

Comment: I'm afraid there is no built-in soulution you need. You rather need something like phantom-js or pupeteer and build own tests.

Comment: "I didn't find any big differences in numbers (as expected)" - so if it was as expected I don't get it. This question is unprecise. What are "decent results"? What are "solid numbers" - do you mean product of three natural numbers? See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: "I didn't find any big differences in numbers (as expected)" - I meant that I've expected seeing differences in numbers when testing performance with and without image reflow issue. I would like to get a prove that image reflow affects performance in a negative way.

Comment: my implementation is using srcset and stuff from that MDN article, but it's not solving my problem

Comment: What problem? You're too cryptic?

Comment: @Zydnar as I said in my question - I'm trying to measure performance benefits of fixing images reflow. I tried to use chrome built-in tools to achieve it - measured on the same site with and without implemented solution for image reflow (and compare it). Results aren't  as expected because measured numbers of site painting and rendering are pretty much the same regardless images reflow. Again, PROBLEM that I'm trying to SOLVE is to PROVE (in numbers) that fixing images reflow will have beneficial impact on site performance.

Comment: Best you can do is either write own browser plugin and somehow connect to devtools performance tab, or write own custom tests on something like phantom.js. I don't know any built-in way to do it. Edit: But it's possible numbers are right difference is not that big. You can ask at chrominium forums about that.

Comment: ok thanks! I know it's pretty problematic, will give a try to phantom.js and wait for more answers